# Elastic Beanstalk CLI - Not replacing instance on deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've just tried making a change to an .ebextensions config file, and doing an "eb deploy", however I noticed when I ssh'd in, that the commands have simply been run again against the same instance.

I had assumed that doing a deploy would replace the instances. I hadn't counted on the commands potentially needing to be re-runnable on a particular instance.

Can someone tell me under what circumstances Elastic Beanstalk will determine it needs to replace the instances?

Is there some way to force a replacement of the instances from the cli?

I should also mention that this is a docker application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone tell me under what circumstances Elastic Beanstalk will
>   determine it needs to replace the instances?

Elastic Beanstalk replaces the instance automatically only when there any underlying issue detected in the instance or the instance becomes unavailable. Other way to change the instance is forcing it with being careful of down time. Where comes your second question.

> Is there some way to force a replacement of the instances from the
>   cli?

This is recommended process for zero down time. Increase the minimum instances in Elastic BeanStalk to 3 and decrease it back to 2 after the third instance is up then terminate the problematic instance. Using CLI below are the steps

```
eb config
```

Change the number of instances in the config file that appears below.

```
aws:autoscaling:asg:
    Availability Zones: Any
    Cooldown: '360'
    Custom Availability Zones: 'us-west-2a,us-west-2b'
    MaxSize: '3'
    MinSize: '1'
```

Once you see the 3 instance up.

You can stop the instance with something like this.

```
ec2-stop-instances i-10a64379
```

And then you can again follow the above step to bring it back to what you want.

Comment: What if there are no problematic instances and we DO NOT want to deploy to a running instance?